# Sennheiser HD 650 vs.600 

Tags: headphones

I'm going to moving out soon, so looking to invest in a good set of headphones. I've been looking at these two for quite a while and I think one of them will do the job nicely. One question though. I have an Alesis io26 interface and was just wondering would I need an amp, or can I plug them straight in to the Alesis?

I know some of you are sick of headphone threads, but if anyone wanted to offer feedback, i would really like to hear from some current users.. Is there a massive difference between the two?

Thank you.

p.s.

I checked the stats for the Alesis and found the following:

Headphone Outputs 
Frequency response: +/-0.1 dB, 22Hz to 22kHz 
Power (@ 32 Ohms): 50mW 
Gain range: 20dB 
THD+N: <0.05 % 
Signal-to-noise ratio: 100 dB, A-weighted 
Output impedance: 32 Ohm 
Load impedance range: 32 to 600 Ohms

Will I be able run the senn's through it?

Comment: it's a bit old this question and likely no longer relevant. Suggest close.

Answer (score 1):

I own SHD650's - AMAZING headphones.

Quarter inch TRS is standard - comes with a 8th inch adapter.

The Alesis is just like any other firewire I/O - you can plug right into the HP jack. The output volume from your DAW is what matters. There is a monitor mix knob so be sure to use reference tones for correct mixing volume.

If you want to bypass the knob, just use your headphone jack as the output and your pre's for your ins. I would check your computer's audio card max sample rate output though - most are 48k as opposed to the I/O or control surfaces' that have 96k playback.

Comment: I have the 650's as well, they're great!

Answer (score 0):

Verkannt the thing you have to know about this is that, the higher the impedance of the headphones the lower the levels are going to be.

To be sure get beyerdynamic DT 770 PRO (80 ohm). There is another model at 250 ohms but it will sound to weak with your setup, in general the lesser the ohms of the headphones the greater the level should be.